# coredata + MagicRecords, how to findAll in background

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I am having this issue ever since i decided to fetch all the data in background by something like this

```
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    /* fetch my data here */
    self.data = [SomeEntity MR_findAll];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableview reloadData];

    });
});
```

It works fine when first start, if you go into another view controller and wait for couples of minute then come back, all the entities found turned into **fault state** and no more attributes are accessible

I was first using GCD for background queue, then i tried create my own queue by

```
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myname.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

it still faults everything

I looked into MagicRecords' sources it seems it automatically creating new context for current thread

I am running out of ideas, please help

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

One good idea to solve this is to dispense with 3rd party frameworks that have unpredictable and untraceable behaviour. You can circumvent this by defaulting to the standard managed object API.

It seems that MR is not playing nice with the table view. The data is too much and core data faults the objects. Instead, implement a plain-vanilla `NSFetchedResultsController` and enjoy its free memory optimisations including automatic faulting and un-faulting of managed objects as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. MR is working as designed.

The tableview UI works in the main thread as do all UIKit UI elements.

You may NOT cross threads with Core-Data which means NSManagedObjects and their associated contexts belong to the thread that created them. Any attempt to cross threads with Core Data will eventually crash.

So you may do background processing in Core Data and merge through to your Main Thread context but somewhere along the line you need to fetch the data you are presenting in the UI in the Main Thread.

So you can do this…

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    [self doSomeHeavyProcessingForSomeEntityThenSaveThreadContext];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.data = [SomeEntity MR_findAll];
        [self.tableview reloadData];

    });
});
```